# Regex Lookahead and lookbehind at most one digit

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for create RegEx pattern

- 8 characters `[a-zA_Z]`
- must contains only one digit in any place of string

I created this pattern:

```
^(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}$
```

This pattern works fine but i want only one digit allowed.  Example:

```
aaaaaaa6   match
aaa7aaaa   match

aaa88aaa   don't match
aaa884aa   don't match
aaawwaaa   don't match
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could instead use:

```
^(?=[0-9a-zA-Z]{8})[^\d]*\d[^\d]*$
```

The first part would assert that the match contains 8 alphabets or digits.  Once this is ensured, the second part ensures that there is only one digit in the match.

EDIT: Explanation:

- The anchors `^` and `$` denote the start and end of string.
- `(?=[0-9a-zA-Z]{8})` asserts that the match contains 8 alphabets or digits.
- `[^\d]*\d[^\d]*` would imply that there is only one digit character and remaining non-digit characters.  Since we had already asserted that the input contains digits or alphabets, the non-digit characters here are alphabets.

Comment: I don't understand second part can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non regex solution, I wrote this for a small project :

```
public static bool ContainsOneDigit(string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) || s.Length != 8)
        return false;
    int nb = 0;
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            return false;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') // just thought, I could use Char.IsDigit() here ...
            nb++;
    }
    return nb == 1;
}
```