# How to make regular expression with only 3 characters and 3 digits?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried the below regex for match here http://rubular.com/ but it matches only 3 characters or 3 digits at a time.

```
^((\d{3})|(\w{3}))$
```

I need result like this:

> 123eee
>
> 4r43fs

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use regex it is quite complicated:

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]).{6}$
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com/v1?38m0v)

This will do what you want.

1. `\w` is not what you want, it also includes `\d` and the underscore "_".
2. `(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check the condition of three digits in the string.
3. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check the condition of three letters in the string.
4. `.{6}` checks for a length of 6 overall

Comment: @Renjith I like your style stema, but in this case, compared with my answer, the many dot-stars cause unnecessary backtracking, as they start out by swallowing the digits and letters that are supposed to follow them.

Comment: @zx, thanks I like your style, too (very similar to me), with the `.*` You are right, yours will find matches in less steps. I don't know if it makes a differences here since the target seems to be a very short string, so I went only for readability of the regex.

Comment: Ha you're right about the limited potential for backtracking (we hope), upvoting your answer for "easy on the eyes." :)

Answer (score 9):

Here you go:

```
^(?=(?:[a-z]*\d){3})(?=(?:\d*[a-z]){3})\w{6}$
```

http://regex101.com/r/hO5jY9

If there are at least three digits, at least three letters, and at most six characters, the string has to match.

**How does this work?**

1. This is a classic password-validation-style regex.
2. The two lookaheads check that we have at least three digits and at least three letters
3. After these assertions, we are free to match any 6 characters with `\w{6}` until the end of the string

**The lookaheads**

Let's break down the first lookahead: `(?=(?:[a-z]*\d){3})`

It asserts that three times (`{3}`), at this position in the string, which is the start of the string as asserted by `^`, we are able to match any number of letters, followed by a single digit. This mean there must be at least three digits.

Answer (score 8):

One lookahead should be enough to check, if there are exactly 3 digits:

```
^(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){3}$)[^\W_]{6}$
```

Used `[^\W_]` as shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

[test on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kN7zX9)

Comment: +1 for the more comprehensive regex, it should also do what is wanted, but it is more complex and more difficult to understand.

Comment: @stema On the contrary, I'd say that this is more obvious about what it'd do.

Comment: Upvoting you for the most compact (and perhaps elegant) alternative. :)

Comment: @devnull, to be clear, I like this regex it is very clever. But I don't think it is obvious what it is doing. To understand it you need to have a quite deep understanding of regexes, I am sure if your read this after some weeks again in your own code, you will need some time to understand again what it is doing.

Comment: @stema I've used [similar forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22436104/2235132) in the past.  Perhaps that was the reason this seemed to be easier to understand.  I agree that it might not to obvious to everybody :)

Comment: @zx81 your answer has my appreciation already :) thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2):

```
function checker(data) {
    var splitted = data.split(/\d/);
    if (splitted.length === 4) {
        return splitted.join("").split(/[a-zA-Z]/).length === 4;
    }
    return false;
}

console.assert(checker("123eee") === true);
console.assert(checker("4r43fs") === true);
console.assert(checker("abcd12") === false);
console.assert(checker("4444ab") === false);
console.assert(checker("ab1c")   === false);
console.assert(checker("444_ab") === false);
```

Comment: This will also declare a string such as "444_ab" valid. I believe the OP wanted numbers and word characters only.

Comment: Although to be fair `\w` matches an underscore anyway, so the down vote was incorrect. I also learnt a new command in `console.assert` so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match any six-character combination of digits and "word characters" use:

```
/^[\d\w]{6}$/
```

Comment: I thought the same. Apparently **only** 3 of each. But in any possible permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we can do this in two ways.

If you need IE7 support " ? " expression will give some issues .So you can check like below.

```
[\d\w]{6} && ![\d]{6} && ![\w]{6}
```

1. check for combination
2. check for only digit or not
3. check for only alphabets.